# Can a headless zombie eat your plants?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

In Plants vs Zombies, often, when a zombie loses its head, it continues making munching motions.  I usually freak out and bomb them with something when they get that close, but I'm curious if it continues to damage your plants.

Comment: I could swear they can still hurt the plant with their hands until they fall down, but then again, I vaguely remember (somehow) determining that once they lose their head, nothing happens.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When a zombie loses his head it is a signal that he is really dead now and it doesn't do any further damage to your plants.

Comment: Just for reference - while it can't do any **damage** directly, it can still be a negative influence, since the headless body - until it falls - will still absorb your plants' 1 or 2 shots thus shielding any zombies behind it.

Answer (score 5):

No, once the zombie is dead it won't to any more damage, regardless of what the death animation might look like.

Comment: True, sound != damage.